# Leaflet сместить векторный слой на яндекс карте?

Tags: javascript, vector, leafletjs

Использую библиотеку Leaflet, подключил тайлы Яндекса

```
var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://vec{s}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=4.55.2&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}&scale=2&lang=ru_RU', {
    subdomains:['01', '02', '03', '04'], 
    reuseTiles: true, 
    updateWhenIdle: false
});
```

Изменил проекцию в соответствии с картой

```
map.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG3395;
```

Сверху накатил границы РФ, сделанные для OSM от Mapzen

```
L.geoJSON(russianBorders).addTo(map);
```

Граница легла как надо, но появляется первая проблема - 180 меридиан разрезающий Чукотку, и не повторяющиеся границы на рядом лежащих тайлах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате долгих раздумий использовал плагин Leaflet.VectorGrid и его класс slicer для наложения векторных слоев опирающихся на geoJSON. Получилось следующее:

```
L.vectorGrid.slicer(russianBorders, vectorTileOptions).addTo(map);
```

В итоге проблемы выше были решены, но появилась другая - VectorGrid игнорирует проекцию EPSG3395 из за чего появляется смещение границы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить это смещение? Или может кто знает другой способ решения проблем "180 меридиана" и повторяемости границ тайлов?